# \mathop applied on colon

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, math-operators

I thought I knew when `\mathop` centers its argument on the math axis and when it does not, but apparently I'm wrong (admittedly, that happens rather often `:-)`).

```
\documentclass{article}   

\begin{document}
$- h - \mathop{h} -$

$- : - \mathop{:} - \mathop: -$
\end{document}
```

This produces (the minus signs are there only to show the math axis)

[image]

Now, my understanding was that `\mathop` centers its argument on the math axis when the argument is a single symbol. However, bracing the colon here hoes wrong. What's the issue?

Comment: Looks like very sharp eyes.

Comment: @albert Thank you `:-)` Jokes aside, you'd see it better with `=` instead of `-`. I haven't got time to change the picture right now, maybe later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}   
\showoutput
\begin{document}
$- h - \mathop{h} -$

$\mathop{h} - : - \mathop{:} - \mathop: - \showlists$
\end{document}
```

produces

```
### math mode entered at line 6
\mathop
.\fam1 h
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^@
\mathrel
.\fam0 :
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^@
\mathop
.\mathrel
..\fam0 :
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^@
\mathop
.\fam0 :
\mathbin
.\fam2 ^^@
### horizontal mode entered at line 6
```

Where you see that because `h` is a mathord, `\mathop{h}` ends up with a `mathop` node with a single child field of a character node, so it gets centred, but `\mathop{:}` ends up as a `mathop` node with a `mathrel` field so not centred and `\mathop:` changes the type of the node so directly constructs a `mathop` node containing `:` so is centred.

Comment: Uhm... well, I see what is going on. I'm not yet sure I understand it... `;-)`

Comment: @campa: Well, just think of this: `\mathop:` is a single character turned into an Op atom, while `\mathop{:}` is a *subformula* (namely, `{:}`) turned into an Op atom.  The “center-on-the-math-axis” feature of `\mathop` is only activated when the Op atom consists of a single character (see _The TeXbook_, Appendix G, Rule 13, more precisely the top of p. 444).